# Why does this code produce an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

Could someone explain this problem...

Why does:

```
String letters[] = { "A", "B", "C" };
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(3);

for(int i=2 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    list.set(i,letters[i]);


for(int i=0 ; i < list.size() ; i++)
    System.out.print(list.get(i));
```

Produce an:
`IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `new ArrayList<String>(3)` creates an `ArrayList` with an **initial capacity** of 3, NOT a list with 3 elements:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(3);
list.size();//output 0
```

So when you call `list.set(i,letters[i])` for the first time, you are trying to access element 2, which does not exist.

On the other hand, this code would work the way you intend it to:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Collections.nCopies(3, null));
```